# I can't add UIBezierPath to CAEmitterCell's contents variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, uibezierpath, caemitterlayer

I could not add an icon I drew with UIBezierPath to CAEmitterCell. I wonder if the icon is not drawn? ShapeView does not work when I run the application. However, you may find that the ShapeView works when you use it normally.

So do I have a chance to convert UIBezierPath to image?

Can it actually be done without converting to image?

**Using**

```
struct GameView: View {
    
    ....
    let playerBounds = UIBezierPath.calculateBounds(paths: [.none, .playerX, .playerO])
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            ParticleEffectView(particleImages: [ShapeView(bezier: .playerX, pathBounds: playerBounds), ShapeView(bezier: .playerO, pathBounds: playerBounds)])
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

**Shape View**

```
struct ShapeView: Shape {
    let bezier: UIBezierPath
    let pathBounds: CGRect
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let pointScale = (rect.width >= rect.height) ? max(pathBounds.height, pathBounds.width) : min(pathBounds.height, pathBounds.width)
        let pointTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1/pointScale, y: 1/pointScale)
        let path = Path(bezier.cgPath).applying(pointTransform)
        let multiplier = min(rect.width, rect.height)
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: multiplier, y: multiplier)
        return path.applying(transform)
    }
}
```

**UIBezier Path**

```
extension UIBezierPath {
    
    static func calculateBounds(paths: [UIBezierPath]) -> CGRect {
        let myPaths = UIBezierPath()
        for path in paths {
            myPaths.append(path)
        }
        return (myPaths.bounds)
    }
    
    static var playerX: UIBezierPath {
        let shape = UIBezierPath()
        shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 48.04, y: 33.28))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 62.04, y: 19.28))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 62.04, y: 3.96), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 66.28, y: 15.05), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 66.28, y: 8.19))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 46.72, y: 3.96), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 57.81, y: -0.27), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 50.96, y: -0.27))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.72, y: 17.96))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 18.71, y: 3.96))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 3.39, y: 3.96), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 14.48, y: -0.27), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 7.62, y: -0.27))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 3.39, y: 19.28), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: -0.84, y: 8.18), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: -0.84, y: 15.05))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 17.4, y: 33.28))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 3.39, y: 47.29))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 3.39, y: 62.61), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: -0.84, y: 51.52), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: -0.84, y: 58.38))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 18.71, y: 62.61), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 7.62, y: 66.84), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 14.48, y: 66.84))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32.72, y: 48.6))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 46.72, y: 62.61))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 62.04, y: 62.61), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 50.96, y: 66.84), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 57.81, y: 66.84))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 62.04, y: 47.29), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 66.28, y: 58.38), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 66.28, y: 51.52))
        shape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 48.04, y: 33.28))
        shape.close()
        return shape
    }
    
    static var playerO: UIBezierPath {
        let shape = UIBezierPath()
        shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 32.5, y: 0))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 32.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 14.55, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 14.55))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 32.5, y: 65), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50.45), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 14.55, y: 65))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 65, y: 32.5), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 50.45, y: 65), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 65, y: 50.45))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 32.5, y: 0), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 65, y: 14.55), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 50.45, y: 0))
        shape.close()
        shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 32.01, y: 49.24))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 15.76, y: 32.99), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 23.03, y: 49.24), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 15.76, y: 41.97))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 32.01, y: 16.74), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 15.76, y: 24.02), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 23.03, y: 16.74))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 48.26, y: 32.99), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 40.98, y: 16.74), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 48.26, y: 24.02))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 32.01, y: 49.24), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 48.26, y: 41.97), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 40.98, y: 49.24))
        shape.close()
        return shape
    }
    
    static var none: UIBezierPath {
        let shape = UIBezierPath()
        return shape
    }
}
```

**Particle Effect View**

```
struct ParticleEffectView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var particleImages: [ShapeView]
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        
        let host = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        
        let particlesLayer = CAEmitterLayer()
        particlesLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        host.layer.insertSublayer(particlesLayer, at: 0)
        host.layer.masksToBounds = true
        host.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
        particlesLayer.backgroundColor = .none
        particlesLayer.emitterShape = .circle
        particlesLayer.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: 509.4, y: 707.7)
        particlesLayer.emitterSize = CGSize(width: 1648.0, height: 1112.0)
        particlesLayer.emitterMode = .outline
        particlesLayer.renderMode = .backToFront
        
        particlesLayer.emitterCells = prepareParticeCell(particles: particleImages)
        return host
    }
    
    func prepareParticeCell(particles: [ShapeView]) -> [CAEmitterCell] {
        
        var arrayParticleCell: [CAEmitterCell] = [CAEmitterCell]()
        
        for particleItem in particles {
            
            let particleCell: CAEmitterCell = CAEmitterCell()
            
            particleCell.contents = particleItem
            particleCell.name = "XO"
            particleCell.birthRate = 1
            particleCell.lifetime = 74.5
            particleCell.velocityRange = 0.0
            particleCell.velocity = 79.0
            particleCell.xAcceleration = 0.0
            particleCell.yAcceleration = 0.0
            particleCell.emissionLatitude = 1*6.0 * (.pi / 180)
            particleCell.emissionLongitude = -105.0 * (.pi / 180)
            particleCell.emissionRange = 360.0 * (.pi / 180.0)
            particleCell.spin = -65.6 * (.pi / 180.0)
            particleCell.spinRange = 314.2 * (.pi / 180.0)
            particleCell.scale = 0.010
            particleCell.scaleRange = 0.01
            particleCell.scaleSpeed = 0.02
            particleCell.alphaRange = 0.0
            particleCell.alphaSpeed = 0.47
            particleCell.color = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            
            arrayParticleCell.append(particleCell)

        }

        return arrayParticleCell
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        uiView.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
particleCell.contents = particleItem
```

there is no compile-time error, but at runtime nothing happens either. That is because the only thing an emitter cell `contents` can be is a CGImage (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caemittercell/1522109-contents)) — and a ShapeView, quite obviously, is not a CGImage. Setting the `contents` to anything else other than a CGImage is not an error but is ineffective, and figuring out what the issue is can take a long time. I have often complained to Apple about this.

Comment: Can I convert UIBezierPath to image?

Comment: You can draw a UIBezierPath into an image graphics context and extract the image. But that, it seems to me, is a different question.